# Mobile opera have background sound support?

Tags: audio, mobile, opera

I make browser/html/js games.

One of my biggest pains in the arse is the lack of background sound support in mobile safari. This lack of support makes high value games pretty much impossible.

Does anyone know if opera mini supports html5 audio, or any mobile browser for that matter.

If not, what are some alternatives methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Opera standards support chart](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2010/03/16/opera-standards-chart), audio in HTML 5 isn't supported neither in Opera Mobile, nor in Opera Mini.